# How does casting an arguments influence an overriding and overloading method in java?

Tags: java, casting, overloading, overriding

I learned about polymorphism in java and when a method in (child) extends class will override a method in the parent class, also when will a method overload other method.

this website helped me a lot understanding those issues.
But, I didn't find anything that explain what and how casting an object, and/or casting the argument passing to the method influence the method overriding and overloading.

One example of casting and overloading:

```
public class A{
  private int num;
  public A(int n){
    num = n;
  }

  public int getNum(){
    return num;
  }

  public boolean f(A a){
    return num == a.num * 2;
  }
  }


public class B extends A {
  public B(int n){
    super(n);
  }

  public boolean f(B b){
    return getNum() == b.getNum();
  }
}


public class C extends A {
  public C(int n){
    super(n);
  }

  public boolean f(A a){
    return a instanceof C && getNum() == a.getNum();
  }
}
```

---

Consder this lines of code:

```
A y1 = new B(10);
C z2 = new C(10);
System.out.println(z2.f((C)y1));
```

how will effect the cast of y1?
I am interested in the general idea... how does casting affect in overloading and overriding?

Comment: `y1` is not an instance of `C`. Whatever is going on here is not something I would call sane.

Comment: Casting is not related to overloading or overriding. See casting objects section here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: wait....casting y1 to C is impossible. Also, if you can write all these out, maybe simply running these code will get you the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Type casting changes a reference from one type to another

Overloading is when 2 functions with the same name accept different parameters, and the correct function is executed based on the parameters

Overriding is when a child class's method replaces or overwrites the same method from its base class

I don't see what casting has to do with overriding or overloading

Comment: Casting doesn't change the object's type, but rather the reference's type. You can't cast an Object to a String (or you can, but you'll get a `ClassCastException`).

Comment: That is what I meant, gotta stop mixing up my terminology

Answer (score 1):

Casting objects will not affect how overridden methods are called, which means calls to `f(A)` remain unaffected.

However, they can still affect which overloaded method is actually used. Do note that `f(B)` in class `B` does not really override `f(A)`. Rather, it is an overload of the method:

```
 public class B extends A {
   //...
   public boolean f(B b) {... } // implements function accepting a B reference argument

   // since it extends A, this method also exists, and is implemented by class A:
   //public boolean f(A a);
 }
```

If you were to cast `y1` to `B`, for example, you would then be calling method `f(B)` instead.

```
 A y1 = new B(10);
 B z2 = new B(10);
 System.out.println(z2.f(y1); // calls z2.f(A), implemented by class A
 System.out.println(z2.f((B)y1)); // calls z2.f(B)
```

This happens because reference types are changed with casts, which then are associated to a possibly distinct method signature.

Comment: can this happened also in the opposite direction? for example:

Comment: B y1 = new B(10);
 B z2 = new B(10);
System.out.println(z2.f((A)y1));

Comment: for calling to the method on class A...?

Comment: As explained in the last sentence, yes. Whatever changes the reference types of method arguments might change the overload method call, and that would happen in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you code example won't run because an instance of `A`, `y1`, cannot be cast to a `C`.

That said I think what you are asking is how the reference type effects the method being called.

The first important point is that **Java uses static binding when methods are overloaded**.

Static binding in Java works with the reference type, which can be changed by casting, hence why given:

- the classes `A` and `B` where `B` extends `A`
- overloaded methods `public void f(A a)` and `public void f(B b)`

This would happen:

```
A a = new B();
B b = new B();

f(a);    //calls f(A a)   
f(b);    //calls f(B b)   
f((B)a); //calls f(B b)
```

The next important point is that **Java uses dynamic binding when methods are overriden**.

Dynamic binding in Java works on the instance type, hence why given:

- the class `C` that defines the method `public void f(String s)`
- the class `D` that extends `C` and overrides the method `public void f(String s)`

This would happen:

```
C c = new C();
D d = new D();

c.f("hello");      //calls C.f(String s)
d.f("hello");      //calls D.f(String s)
((C)d).f("hello"); //calls D.f(String s)
```

Comment: I fail to see the 3 overloaded `f`s in `C`. The class extends A and does not declare new overloads, unlike `B`. You probably mean "overridden" in some of your sentences.

Comment: @E_net4 oops, sorry, there's two method 'f's on 'C', let me correct

Comment: Again, that is still wrong. What we have in class `C` is the method `f(A)`, which is simply overridden from `A`. You cannot call these different overloads. Let us not confuse overloading with overriding.

Comment: @E_net4 right, the example code in intentionally confusing, missed the extends being from `A` - gonna stop trying to make sense of the code and answer what I think is being asked, which is how overloaded methods are resolved

Comment: **Overloading is completely resolved at compile time.** Mentioning overloading and dynamic binding in one sentence is totally wrong. Please correct that part of your answer. It seems, you really meant _overriding_ instead of _overloading_ in that sentence, although the example describes overloading.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose not concentrating on this one, actually meant 'static binding'

Comment: @NickHolt Ok. That makes more sense now (so I also removed the downvote). In my opinion this is one of the important points in an answer to this question. And we should take great care of the wording, especially when speaking to beginners.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes, I rattled that off before lunch :-z

Comment: @NickHolt Nevermind. Glad as I could take your answer as an opportunity to show off. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're getting confused with TypeCasting & Polymorphism. Another bad thing I've seen in your code is that you've typecast one subclass to another subclass. Always remember, TypeCasting between subclasses aren't possible.

If a method's formal argument define SuperClass reference & you're passing in ConcreteClass reference as actual argument then it is called **Widening** which is not needed to typecast. But If a method's formal argument define ConcreteClass reference & you're passing in SuperClass reference as actual argument then it is called **Narrowing** & you must explicitly typecast.

Typecasting & Polymorphism are different stories. Following is the best example of polymorphism I've ever seen.

```
public class Character {

    private Weapon weapon;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Character hero = new Character();
        Sword s1 = new Sword();
        Weapon s2 = new Sword();

        //s1 = s2;                    Weapon isn't Sword
        s1 = (Sword)s2;             //Narrowing

        hero.setWeapon(s1);
        hero.performAttack();

    hero.setWeapon(new ShotGun());
    hero.performAttack();
    }

    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void performAttack(){
        weapon.performAttack();
    }
}

interface Weapon {
    public void performAttack();
}

class Sword implements Weapon {

    @Override
    public void performAttack() {
        System.out.println("Slashing enemies");
    }
}

class ShotGun implements  Weapon {

    @Override
    public void performAttack() {
        System.out.println("Shooting enemies");
    }
}
```